# Can we say that $\int_{\mathbb R} f(x) f(1+x) dx = \int_{\mathbb R} f(x) f(1-x) dx$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Assume that $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ nice function so that everything  below make sense.

We know that by a change of variable we have $\int_{\mathbb R} f(x) dx = \int_{\mathbb R} f(-x) dx.$

> Can we say that $\int_{\mathbb R} f(x) f(1+x) dx = \int_{\mathbb R} f(x) f(1-x) dx$?

Comment: Looks rather unlikely to me.

Comment: Or I could certainly buy $\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)\,f(x+1)\,dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)\,f(x-1)\,dx,$ though that doesn't say much (just a translation).

Comment: Problem is, on the one hand your two function calls are traversing the domain the same direction; in the other integral, they're traversing in opposite directions.

Comment: Building on @AdrianKeister's idea:  $\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)\,f(x+1)\,dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(-x)\,f(1-x)\,dx$ would also work.  This implies that the statement is true for any even function $f$, or any function with reflection symmetry about $x = 1$ (i.e., $f(1 - x) = f(1 + x)$.)

Answer (score 3):

No. As a counterexample, take $f=\chi_{[0,1]} $.

Comment: You can say that $\int_{\mathbb R} f(x) f(1+x) dx = \int_{\mathbb R} f(x-1) f(x) dx$, however.